# Mathematics operation between two columns inside oracle database (Describe the desired result)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have the following table :

```
Name    Department  first_deg   second_deg  
John    IT              20          20      
David   Art             30          60      
Kadir   Music           40          85      
kevin   Sport           50          140
```

i would like to do some query in sql that will do some mathematics operation and find the result between the (first_deg,second_deg)

for example :
if first_deg,second_deg they are equal it will write null
if first_deg double than second_deg it will write null
other wise it must give the different .

for more explain the result should be like :

```
Name    Department  first_deg   second_deg  result
John    IT              20          20      null
David   Art             30          60      null
Kadir   Music           40          85      5
kevin   Sport           50          140     40
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: What should happen if second is < first?

Comment: `CASE WHEN second_deg NOT IN (first_deg, 2*first_deg) THEN second_deg - 2 * first_deg END`

Comment: between the first and second it must find the different and put it in the result colm :

if second_deg = first_deg ---> result null.............
if second_deg =2( first_deg) ---> result null .............
if second_deg = 2(first_deg)+9 ---> result 9

Comment: In Oracle you can do `nullif(mod(second_deg, first_deg), 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do

```
select Name  ,  Department , first_deg ,  second_deg ,
case when first_deg = second_deg then null
     when power(first_deg,2) = second_deg then null 
     when  power(first_deg,2) < second_deg then 
         second_deg - power(first_deg,2) 
  else null -- you did not explained what rule you want here therefore I put null
 end as result 
 from yourtable;
```

Comment: rules :
between the first and second it must find the different and put it in the result colm : if second_deg = first_deg ---> result null............. if second_deg =2( first_deg) ---> result null ............. if second_deg = 2(first_deg)+9 ---> result 9 –

Comment: POWER isn't useful here and this does not yield the required result.

Comment: it is work perfect Thanksssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss so much @Roberto Hernandez

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CASE..WHEN` statement and `MOD` as follows:

```
SELECT T.*, 
       CASE 
         WHEN FIRST_DEG = SECOND_DEG OR SECOND_DEG = 2* FIRST_DEG THEN NULL
         ELSE MOD(SECOND_DEG, FIRST_DEG) 
         END AS RESULT 
    FROM YOUR_TABLE T
```

**Note**: You can use different conditions in `CASE..WHEN` statement as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would write the logic as:

```
(case when second_deg not in (first_deg, first_deg * 2)
      then second_deg - 2 * first_deg
 end) as result
```

Note that there is no `else` clause.  If the condition doesn't match, the `case` expression returns `null`.